# Sometimes xpath is not working but sometimes same xpath is working while running automation

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, xpath-2.0

I wrote one xpath like below:

```
//div[contains(@id,'ext-element-')]/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/div/span
```

Same xpath sometimes it is finding the particular element.But sometimes it is throwing

> ElementNotFoundException.

Is there any convenient way to solve this problem?

Comment: please post your HTML code so that it would be more easy to understand the problem.

Comment: This OP never share the HTML code in past also, even asking too many times

Answer (score 1):

The more elements there are in the xPath (e.g. `tbody/tr/td/div`), the more possibilities it is for it to break (sometimes for mysterious reasons).

Wherever possible, use `descendant` to skip them, for example:

```
//div[contains(@id,'ext-element-')]/table[2]/descendant::span[contains(@id, 'spanId')]
```

Or just double-slash `//` (meaning any child or subchild):

```
  //div[contains(@id,'ext-element-')]/table[2]//span[contains(@id, 'spanId')]
```

Shorter, yes, but less readable (easy to miss a slash and then wonder what happened). But is still mostly prefer double-slash.

The use of "Axis names" can make your xPaths more robust.

Here are some resources:

http://seleniumworks.blogspot.de/2014/03/xpath-selenium-uses-part-ii.html

https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/xpath,-css,-dom-and-selenium-the-rosetta-stone/

http://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html

Answer (score 0):

Does the step prior to this cause a change to the DOM (e.g. new page load or AJAX request that changes the page)? If yes, then is likely to be a timing problem: the element is sometimes not found because the request for the element happened while the page was loading. You should instead wait for the element to exist. Then find the element and do whatever comes next.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help you much, but I was having a similar issue where `driver.find_element_by_xpath(...)` would return information initially, but then running the same thing a couple seconds later would result in the `'Element Not Found'` exception, so I imported time and put a `sleep(2)` right after my `driver.get(...)` and that fixed it for me.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

Always try to go with an absolute path; otherwise try by adding indexes to XPATH; otherwise go for the third option of a relative path (keeping it minimal).